Allure Cypress showing only Cypress commands in Step Execution outcome, but I want BDD / Cucumber output
I use cypress-cucumber-preprocessor + allure-cypress in order to get Allure reporting format.
This is my package.json:
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "13.15.1",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1",
    "cypress-on-fix": "^1.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.15.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
    "mocha": "^10.7.3",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true,
    "stepDefinitions": "cypress/e2e/cucumber"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "allure-commandline": "^2.30.0",
    "allure-cypress": "^3.0.2",
    "allure-js-commons": "^3.0.4",
    "braces": "3.0.3",
    "cypress-file-upload": "^5.0.8",
    "cypress-high-resolution": "^1.0.0",
    "cypress-if": "^1.12.4",
    "cypress-plugin-last-failed": "^1.2.0",
    "mailslurp-client": "^15.20.2"

And this is my cypress.config.js:
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');
const { allureCypress } = require('allure-cypress/reporter');
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default;
const cypressOnFix = require('cypress-on-fix');
const MailSlurp = require('mailslurp-client').default;

module.exports = defineConfig({
  viewportHeight: 1280,
  viewportWidth: 1440,
  defaultCommandTimeout: 7000,
  experimentalMemoryManagement: true,
  numTestsKeptInMemory: 10,
  retries: {
    experimentalStrategy: 'detect-flake-and-pass-on-threshold',
    experimentalOptions: {
      maxRetries: 1,
      passesRequired: 1,
    },
    runMode: true,
    openMode: true,
  },
  screenshotOnRunFailure: true,
  screenshotsFolder: 'cypress/screenshots',
  video: true,
  videosFolder: 'cypress/videos',
  waitForAnimations: true,
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  failOnStatusCode: false,
  e2e: {
    experimentalRunAllSpecs: true,
    testIsolation: true,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3001',
    specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/cucumber/*.feature',
    env: {
      TAGS: 'not @Ignore',
    },
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on = cypressOnFix(on);
      const allurePlugin = allureCypress(on, config, {
        resultsDir: 'allure-results',
        includeCypressCommands: false,
        stepsOnly: true,
        categories: [
          {
            name: 'Known Bugs',
            messageRegex: '.*Error: known bug.*',
            matchedStatuses: ['failed'],
          },
          {
            name: 'Flaky Tests',
            flaky: true,
          },
        ],
        environmentInfo: {
          NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'staging',
          APP_VERSION: process.env.APP_VERSION || '1.0.0',
        },
      });
      on('after:run', (results) => {
        allurePlugin.onAfterRun(results);
      });
      on('file:preprocessor', cucumber());
      on('task', {
        createInbox() {
          const apiKey = 'your-mailslurp-api-key';
          const mailslurp = new MailSlurp({ apiKey });
          return mailslurp.createInbox().then((inbox) => inbox);
        },
        getLatestEmail(inboxId) {
          const apiKey = 'your-mailslurp-api-key';
          const mailslurp = new MailSlurp({ apiKey });
          return mailslurp
            .waitForLatestEmail(inboxId, 30000, true)
            .then((email) => email);
        },
      });

      return config;
    },
  },
});

This is my Allure report page:

I want my testbody to show my cucumber steps, for example:

How can I configure my allureCypress in order to show only cucumber steps in the report?
Already tried
        includeCypressCommands: false,
        stepsOnly: true,
        cucumber: true

but nothing seems to work

The version allure-cypress@3.0.7 should fix the issue.
For more details, please see the pull request: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-js/pull/1205.
